# Download mono-complete and install it on another new machine

Tags: mono, package, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

I Downloaded `mono-complete 3.10` by adding following repository and signing key in synaptic. After Downloading `mono-complete-3.10`, I installed this package in another fresh machine, but in fresh machine it gives lot of errors. Please suggest me how to install this downloaded package on another machine (offline).

Repo:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy/snapshots/3.10.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

Signing Key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see different versions of ubuntu in your tags.
On what version of ubuntu you are installing your mono?
 Did you fully read [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives) article?

Why don't you just use smth like `apt-get install mono-complete monodevelop` e.g.?